# glm::unProject appears to be mixing up the screen Y coordinate

Tags: opengl, projection, coordinate-systems, glm-math, coordinate-transformation

I'm trying to convert my mouse's cursor position in my OpenGL viewport to world coordinates. I'm using `glm::unProject()` to do this. However, it appears that the mouse position's `Y` coordinate is being negated somehow.

If I orient my camera so the world's `Y` axis is pointing up and `X` is pointing right, moving the mouse left/right gives me the correct coordinates, however moving the mouse up/down the `Y` "world" coordinates I get are reversed (positive `Y` goes downwards).

If I reorient the camera so `X` is now going up, `Y` is going left. Moving the mouse left/right gives the right `Y` coordinates, but moving up/down gives reversed `X` coordinates. Same behavior when I orient for `Z`.

[This](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) page mentions that device coordinates use the LHS, maybe this is the cause? Is there something I need to do to handle the case where device coordinates are in a different system? Is there a way to determine that?

---

I'm also noticing that my transformed coordinates are half what they should be (mouse on an object at `(1,0,0)` shows `(0.5,0,0)` but I think this is a separate issue so I'll ask another question once I solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic problem is that OpenGL defines the origin as the lower left corner of the window, while most windowing systems use the upper left instead.  The solution is simple:  subtract the mouse Y coordinate from the window height:

```
gl_x = mouse_x;
gl_y = windowHeight - mouse_y;
```